# Magento 2 EE | How to create/update new record in magento_customerbalance_history table?

Tags: table, create, magento-enterprise-2, history

I am trying it as:

Using the collection

> \Magento\CustomerBalance\Model\Balance\HistoryFactory $historyFactory

As

```
$model = $this->_historyFactory->create();
    //$model->setId(2);
    $model->setData('balance_amount', 333);
    $model->save();
```

But it prompts this exception:

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): A balance is needed
>   to save a balance history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see in file `magento/module-customer-balance/Model/Balance/History.php` line no: 154. You need to set `setBalanceModel` and `setHistoryAction` like this

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


// for Update customer balance history set setHistoryAction(2)

$customerBalance = $obj->create(\Magento\CustomerBalance\Model\BalanceFactory::class)->create()->load(2)->setHistoryAction(2);

$customerBalanceHistory = $obj->create(\Magento\CustomerBalance\Model\Balance\History::class)->create()
        ->setBalanceModel($customerBalance)
        ->setId(2)
        ->setAdditionalInfo('test')
        ->save();    

// for new entry use set setHistoryAction(1)

$customerBalance = $obj->create(\Magento\CustomerBalance\Model\BalanceFactory::class)->create()->load(2)->setHistoryAction(1);

$customerBalanceHistory = $obj->create(\Magento\CustomerBalance\Model\Balance\HistoryFactory::class)->create()
        ->setBalanceModel($customerBalance)
        ->setAdditionalInfo('test')
        ->save();
```

Hope this will solve your problem.